# Check whether internet connectivity available or not in python

Tags: python-2.7

I need to write a program of check the internet connection. If internet connection is available the green light turns on, else the red light turns on.

Please provide me suggestions / ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ping some well-known server?

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to google:

```
import socket
try:
    socket.create_connection(('8.8.8.8',80))
    print 'connected to google'
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'there is no connection'
```

If it return exception, there is no internet connection